# Invalid type argument of unary ‘*’

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have problem with my Arduino C++ code. Here is function:

```
  void sendDeviceName(){
  char buffer[3] = "";
  incomingCommand.toCharArray(buffer, 3);
  int deviceNumber = atoi(*buffer[2]);
  Serial.println(EEPROMreadDevice(deviceNumber));
}
```

When I'm trying compile my code compiler returns:

> error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’

I tried to fix it yourself, but I do not go.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The code doesn't make any sense and in order to make it make sense, we need to know what it's supposed to do. Most likely, you want: `atoi(buffer+2)` (or `atoi(&buffer[2])` instead of `atoi(*buffer[2])`. But it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the fact that `buffer[2]` is a `char`, not a pointer. There is nothing to dereference here. If you are trying to turn a `char` representing a digit into the corresponding `int` value use:

```
int deviceNumber = buffer[2] - '0';
```

Or generally if you want the last N-K chars of a `char` array use:

```
int deviceNumber = atoi(buffer + K);
```

so in your case:

```
int deviceNumber = atoi(buffer + 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`buffer[2]` is a `char`, not a `char *`, so you cannot dereference it.

Comment: THX for help. Now everything is OK

Comment: @bigben: Don't forget to accept answers that solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to fix it yourself, but I do not go.

Well, the expression `buffer[2]` is of type `char`. You cannot dereference a `char`. Perhaps you meant …

```
buffer + 2
```

which is equivalent to

```
&buffer[2]
```

?

That will compile, but as an argument to `atoi` it is wrong: `atoi` requires a zero-terminated string that contains at least one digit, and a pointer to the last element of `buffer` can at best be a pointer to a terminating null-byte (with no digits).

Perhaps this is what you intended:

```
atoi( buffer )
```

Or if you want a digit that's stored at index 2:

```
buffer[2] - '0'
```

(C++ guarantees that the character codes of decimal digits are consecutive).

Or if that `char` value is directly your integer value:

```
buffer[2]
```